# adding interface objects to an array

Tags: typescript

In this snippet of code:

```
let showProjects: IProject[] = []
    for (let i in projects) {
        if (projects[i].show == '1') {
            showProjects.concat(projects[i])
        }
    }
```

I'm concatenating IProject objects to the showProjects array from the projects array if the object has a show value of "1". IProject is an interface which looks like this (notice how the show value at the bottom is a string):

```
export interface IProject {
    project_id: number,
    name: string,
    author: string,
    dateCreated: string,
    components: IComponent[] | null,
    disabled: string,
    show: string
}
```

How can I make the first snippet of code more efficient?

Comment: `showProjects = [...projects.filter(p => p.show === '1')];`? (amended to make a new array).

Comment: ...no, instead do this: ```showProjects = projects.filter(p => p.show === '1');``` you don't need any array destructuring or brackets or anything like that. filter returns a new array